# Shorten the console logs of CheckStyle

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, checkstyle

I am using checkstyle to check the format of my code.

It is working, however when it outputs to the console it gives the absolute path of the file where the warning is occurring:

/Users/someUser/IdeaProjects/project/project-module/src/main/java/MyClass.java:1:15: warning: Missing a Javadoc comment.

I want to remove the first part of the log and get sth like this:

MyClass.java:1:15: warning: Missing a Javadoc comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the property `basedir` for Checker.
https://checkstyle.org/config.html#Checker_Properties

This removes the first part of the path in the violation and leaves what is unique to the path afterwards.

Comment: As an extension to this point..is there a way of setting the basedir property to the absolute path of the user by a variable? I tried ${project.basedir} and ${basedir} but they do not work